# When two siblings in a heap are equal, how do you bubble down?

Tags: data-structures, heaps

I have a heap where both child nodes of the root are 10, and I'd like to perform an operation to remove the min value 9.

I proceed to replacing the root with its next of kin, 18. However when I bubble down, I am unsure of which direction to take.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Picking either should work. The heap property (assuming you have changed it to mean parent $\le$ children) will not be violated.

Comment: I'm thinking that one should randomise the decision for the sake of balancing, but I'm not sure that's necessary.

Comment: @Raphael (binary) heaps are always nearly complete binary trees. What do you mean by balancing?

Comment: @adrianN Yea, forget what I wrote. Thought-knot.